# The concept and circuit of 2 to 4 level converter in 8-QAM

Tags: voltage, modulation

I have a difficulty to understand the basic concept about 2 to 4 level converter in 8-QAM. 
I've google it but still don't understand much except this block is used to convert two voltage into 4 voltage, and that's why i can't start to make the circuit. 
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good idea is to go step by step. 8 QAM (Quadrature Amplitude Modulation) is not the easiest modulation. It combines *amplitude shift keying* (ASK) and *phase shift keying* (PSK) modulation. It is a digital modulation technique, so it is used to transmit a stream of bits in contrast to analog modulation, where the source signals are continuous.

At first we should take a look at the simplest form of digital modulation: 2-ASK, that is an ASK with two possible values per *chip*. In the *baseband* (the NOT yet high frequency modulated signal) there are two possible logic values: 0 and 1. They correspond to two input voltages (e.g. -1V and 1V). Note that we can draw these values as locations in the IQ plane. We will need this later to understand QAM.

[image: ASK modulator, IQ plane and baseband/modulated signals]

To modulate the ASK signal (as shown in the block diagram) the I value is multiplied with the carrier cosine signal. Multiplying with 1V means a cosine impulse is transmitted, multiplying with -1V means an inverted cosine impulse is transmitted (see the table).

[image: ASK vs PSK]

An interesting fact is that inverting the cosine results in the same output signal as delaying it by a half period (180 degree phase shift). This makes 2-ASK equivalent to a 2-PSK modulation. This can be seen in the IQ plane. The ASK idea is to mirror the first location (I=1V) on the Q axis to generate the second location (I=-1V). The PSK idea is to move the first location 180 degree on a circle around the IQ plane origin. Both ideas result in exactly the same locations and therefor in the same signals.

When we want to generate higher order PSK signals (more than two locations in the IQ plane - e.g. 4), we need 90, 180, 270 degree delayed versions of the carrier cosine. They are represented by 4 locations on a circle on the IQ plane. 4 locations mean we can transmit 2 bits in one chip-time, so this effectively increases the channels bitrate:

[image]

To build a delay circuit is costly, so the relation between ASK and PSK is used as a trick to build this device only once. In addition to the original carrier (I path) only one 90 degree shifted version (the Q path) is generated. Using these two signals, all other delayed versions can be created. Take a look at the IQ plane. 180 degree is at (I=-1V, Q=0V), 270 degree is at (I=0V, Q=-1V) and so on. In addition to the ASK modulator a Q path is added to generate the PSK. I and Q path are then just added to form the modulated output signal.

[image]

Each of the I and Q signals can have 3 different values: 1V, 0V, -1V
But there are only 4 allowed combinations, which select one of the 4 locations.  To do that we need some kind of "2 bit to 3 voltage level" converter, which converts two digital input values to the appropriate I and Q voltages as shown in the table:

<kbd>bit0</kbd><kbd>bit1</kbd>:<kbd>I</kbd>  <kbd>Q</kbd>  
--------------------------
  <kbd>0</kbd>   <kbd>0</kbd> :
<kbd>1V</kbd><kbd>0V</kbd>
  <kbd>0</kbd>   <kbd>1</kbd> :
<kbd>0V</kbd><kbd>1V</kbd>
  <kbd>1</kbd>   <kbd>1</kbd> :
<kbd>-1V</kbd><kbd>0V</kbd>
  <kbd>1</kbd>   <kbd>0</kbd> :
<kbd>0V</kbd><kbd>-1V</kbd>

In general the matching of input bit patterns to locations is arbitrary, but in theory it can be shown that the Bit Error Rate is lower, when the locations are mapped using the gray code (as in the table).

These 4 locations have the same distance to the origin of the IQ plane, so the respective output signals have the same amplitude (here: 1V). The only information of the signal is stored in its phase, ergo this is a PSK.

The only difference to PSK is that QAM also changes the amplitude of the signal:

[image]

The image shows (one of the many possible) 8 location QAM. 8 locations mean 3 bits per chip. The locations obviously have different distances to the origin. In this case we need 4 different voltages each for the I and Q signals to reach the locations. This means we need some circuit which converts 3 digital input values (2 voltage levels) to the appropriate I and Q combinations (4 voltage levels each). **-> your 2 to 4 voltage converter**

This is the same thing as for PSK, again. Just one more bit and one more voltage, resulting in a somewhat larger table. I and Q are then feed to the well known modulator that was already used for PSK.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a simplified explanation of what you are trying to achieve: -**

In 8-QAM you combine 3 consecutive bits to form a "number" that can be represented on a two dimensional XY graph: -

[image]

The two dimensional number represents how the carrier is modulated so, for instance 000 would move the carrier to position 000 on the graph. But what does this mean? How does the carrier move to a position on a graph - the unmodulated carrier is repesented by the origin of the graph and "outward" movements are equivalent to amplitude modulations. Rotation  represents angle movements in the carrier (a continuous angle movement is a frequency shift of the carrier).

With no angle modulation the x axis *could be* regarded as the amplitude of the carrier and if it continuously went from - to + (on this axis) it is double sideband suppressed carrier. With a fixed radial (outward) position, and only rotational modulation, this is like FM.

The common terms used are I and Q modulation. There are other ways 8-QAM can be achieved: -

[image]

This version uses 8 points that represent three binary digits in a square formation but there are only 2 Q values and 2 I values used. The previous picture used 4 Q values and 4 I values and I think it is the first version that is nearest to what you are trying to achieve.

The conversion from binary bits to different levels can be done with 2 DACs - one will produce analogue values that feed the Q modulator circuit and one will produce analogue values that feed the I modulator. There are various ways that this can be done and [this](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/8QAM) is a good article. Short summary: -

[image]

Comment: Actually it is not correct, that the value on the Q axis controls the angle and I the amplitude. The IQ plane is a **Complex Plane**. The amplitude is proportional to the distance of the point to the origin. The phase is equivalent to the angle in polar coordinates.

Comment: @Alexander I was giving a much simplified explanation but i'll take your advise and represent the data better.